# value retrieval from XML string having multiple element name and values in it

Tags: jquery, xml

Can anyone help me in retrieving the value of Category in the below sample XML:

```
xx
xx
xx
<worknotes>
Detailed Description:xxx-- MM Info:xxx-- Opened by:xxxOpened at: 2020-11-25 20:21:22Email:aa@aa.com Entity: xxx Location:xxxCategory:xxxxxx
Site:xxxx
Service:xxx
WorkInfo:xxx
</worknotes>
xx
xx
xx
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery code you could read that xml file and split by a common char, in your case colon ":"

```
var your_id = $(this).attr("the_id");
var splitIt = your_id.split(":");
var id = splitIt[1]; // it return an array of split string
```